# Using cuda vector type float 4 when size of vector is not divisible by 4

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda

I'm trying to understand how cuda vector types work. Assume I have a matrix with n rows and m columns and m is not divisible by 4. Matrix is linearized and stored in GPU main memory. Is it possible to use float4 data type and read the first element of the second vector? I wrote a very simple kernel to see how it works, but based on the way I used I can't access the first element of the second vector. Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

__global__ void ker(float * a,int n, int m)
{
        float4 f;
        f=reinterpret_cast<float4*>(a)[1];
        printf("%f %f %f %f,",f.x,f.y,f.z,f.w);

}
int main()
{
        int n=2,m=5;
        float *a=new float[n*m];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
                for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
                        {
                                a[i*m+j]=rand()%10;
                                cout<<a[i*m+j]<<" ";

                        }
                cout<<"\n";
        }
        float * dev_a;
        cudaMalloc ((void**)&dev_a,sizeof(float)*m*n);
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, sizeof(float) * m* n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
        ker<<<1,1>>>(dev_a,n,m);
        gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError());
        cudaFree(dev_a);
        delete []a;
        return 0;
}
```

In the code, I have a matrix with 2 rows and 5 columns, since 5 is not divisible by 4, how can I print the first four elements of the second row of the matrix in the kernel while using float 4? If the data is like:

> 2 3 4 5 9
>
> 4 2 5 9 1

`f=reinterpret_cast<float4*>(a)[1];` reads the data chunk `9 4 2 5` and `f=reinterpret_cast<float4*>(a)[2];` reads `9 1 0 0` which is not what I want (`4 2 5 9`). Is there any way that I can read the first four elements of the second row while using float4?

I know one possible way is padding extra number like 0 at the end of each row to make it divisible by 4, but I'm looking for a solution without manipulating data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The very short answer is that you cannot do this as you imagine. CUDA imposes an alignment limit on types which means that the "correct" pointer alias:

```
f = *reinterpret_cast<float4*>(a+m);
```

is illegal, because the alignment requirement isn't satisfied (`a+m` with `m=5` does not align correctly to a `float4` boundary). On older toolchains/hardware, this would produce a runtime error. On newer hardware/toolchains, it will compile into something that will run without error, but the read is automagically realigned and the result is not what you would expect.

However, you can use `cudaMallocPitch` and `cudaMemcpy2D` to allocate pitched linear memory on the device, and the copy the data you have so that the device copy is correctly aligned, and what you are trying to do will work. If you change your code to something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
    if (code != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
        if (abort) exit(code);
    }
}

template<typename T, typename T0>
struct pitchedpointer
{
    char *p;
    size_t pitch;

    __host__ __device__ pitchedpointer() {};
    __host__ __device__
    pitchedpointer(T0* _p, size_t _pitch) : p(reinterpret_cast<char*>(_p)), pitch(_pitch) {};
    __device__ __host__
    T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) {
        T* v = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p + i*pitch);        
        return v[j]; 
    }
    __device__ __host__
    const T& operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const {
        T* v = reinterpret_cast<T*>(p + i*pitch);        
        return v[j]; 
    }
};

__global__ void ker(float * a, int m, int n, size_t pitch)
{
    int row = threadIdx.x;
    pitchedpointer<float4,float> p(a, pitch);
    float4 f = p(row,1);
    printf("%d: %f %f %f %f\n", row, f.x, f.y, f.z, f.w);
}
int main()
{
    int n=4,m=9;
    float *a=new float[n*m];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
        {
            a[i*m+j]=rand()%10;
            cout << a[i*m+j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    float * dev_a;
    size_t pitch;
    int m4 = 1 + (m-1)/4;
    gpuErrchk( cudaMallocPitch((void**)&dev_a, &pitch, sizeof(float4)*m4, n) );
    gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy2D(dev_a, pitch, a, sizeof(float)*m, sizeof(float)*m, n, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) );
    ker<<<1,n>>>(dev_a, m, n, pitch);
    gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
    gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    delete []a;
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

which does this:

```
~/SO$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 float4align.cu 
~/SO$ ./a.out 
3 6 7 5 3 5 6 2 9 
1 2 7 0 9 3 6 0 6 
2 6 1 8 7 9 2 0 2 
3 7 5 9 2 2 8 9 7 
0: 3.000000 5.000000 6.000000 2.000000
1: 9.000000 3.000000 6.000000 0.000000
2: 7.000000 9.000000 2.000000 0.000000
3: 2.000000 2.000000 8.000000 9.000000
```

As you can see, it correctly access the individual rows of the matrix as a `float4` without  violating the alignment requirements (I chose to print the second `float4` from each row, which is similarly misaligned). The class I introduced is just some sugar to simplify/hide the pointer arithmetic required to use pitched memory on the device, which is described in the `cudaMallocPitch` [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g32bd7a39135594788a542ae72217775c).